# How to set the PYTHONPATH when working with uvicorn?

Tags: python, pythonpath, modulenotfounderror, uvicorn

I am working with a Python program (**main.py**) that relies on a homebrew module (**myhomebrewmodule**).

main.py is located *inside* the myhomebrewmodule folder.

If I was running main.py from an IDE, I would simply add the path to myhomebrewmodule to the PYTHONPATH.

I could also [temporarily add this path to the PYTHONPATH from the terminal](https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-add-a-new-path-to-your-PYTHONPATH-to-import-your-own-python-modules-or-packages-/).

**But how should I proceed when working with uvicorn?**

When I try:

`export PYTHONPATH="pathtomyhomebrewmodule"`

Followed by:

`uvicorn main:app --reload`

I stumble across a ModuleNotFoundError.

Answer (score 2):

> I could also temporarily add this path to the PYTHONPATH from the terminal.

I guess, that is a way to go and not too hard to achieve. It's temporary in terms of 'as long as the app is running' and that's sufficient.

> But how should I proceed when working with uvicorn?

Assuming a directory structure like this:

```
/path/to/project/
    |- project/
        |- main.py
        |- utils.py
    |- start.sh
    |- venv/
```

I introduced a `start.sh` script that looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -Eeuo pipefail

PYTHONPATH=project/:/path/to/myhomebrewmodule/ ./venv/bin/uvicorn project.main:app --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8080 --reload
```

I am assuming you are using a python `virtualenv`, hence the `venv` folder.

As you can see, `PYTHONPATH` was changed to include `project/` as well as `/path/to/myhomebrewmodule/`.

---

`PYTHONPATH` could also be exported directly, which might improve the `start.sh` script's readability (shortened):

```
export PYTHONPATH=project/:/path/to/myhomebrewmodule/
./venv/bin/uvicorn project.main:app --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8080 --reload
```

I hope this helps and not too late ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since uvicorn 0.11.7 you can specify app directory with `--app-dir` option

```
uvicorn --app-dir c:\users\user\projects\new_app\backend\src app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
```