Procfile for buildpack when uvicorn not detecting to the src folder
I'm defining this Procfile:
web: uvicorn src.main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-8080}

But the module inside src is not detected by main.py, why?
For example src/tokenizer.py is not recognized, it said ImportError
Here is output:
(.venv) D:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone>uvicorn src.main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\Scripts\uvicorn.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 409, in main
    run(
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 575, in run
    server.run()
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 65, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 69, in serve
    await self._serve(sockets)
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 76, in _serve
    config.load()
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 433, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 22, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "d:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\.venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 19, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\ssd-sync\KODING\python\cyber-neural-network-capstone\src\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tokenizer import generate_token, validate_token
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tokenizer'

Here is main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, UploadFile, Header
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel
from tokenizer import generate_token, validate_token
from datetime import timedelta
from fastapi.logger import logger
# import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import logging
from infer import infer_image
from uploader import upload_temporary_file


Solved by specifying --app-dir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042519/how-to-set-the-pythonpath-when-working-with-uvicorn
